# iTunesConnect Version Control

Tags: xcode, ios4, ios5, app-store-connect

I was wondering if I upload an app that is for ios 4.2, then once it is released, upload an update of that same app for ios 5.0, that contains ios 5.0 specific features, and it is released. Will users that have ios 4.2 be prompted that there is a new version even though they could not download it. And would that 4.2 version no longer be visible in the app store to those who are on 4.2 and have not downloaded the app yet?

I am asking this because apps that I create have always been for 4.2 to get a large range of downloads, but I wish to release an app that has features only ios 5 has but don't want to lose all those 4.2 downloaders so I want to have a 4.2 version and a 5.0 version, is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iOS 4.2 users will be prompted to download the new version, which wont run on their device. The iOS 4.2 would no longer be available for download.

You could integrate the iOS 5 only features in a iOS 4.2 app in a way that they are optional and only showing up on a device with iOS 5 installed.